# React-typescript with react-router. Params state problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I am using React with typescript and react router. I have a problem. I want to navigate to the filterParam but first call I get in the browser tab I get `"?filter="` in URL, but before `Navigate()` I use setFilterParam and the Navigate does not get the newest state. Why?

```
 const [filterParams, setFilterParams] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const onChosenFilterHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const content = e.target.value;
    setFiltersParams(prevParams => [...prevParams, content])
    let definePath = `?filter=`;
    for (const filter of filterParams) {
      definePath += filter;
    }
    if (e.target.checked) {
      dispatch(
        recipeAction.addFilters({
          content: content,
          filterName: props.filterName,
        })
      );
    }

    if (!e.target.checked) {
      dispatch(
        recipeAction.removeFilters({
          content: content,
          filterName: props.filterName,
        })
      );
    }

    navigate(definePath);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

setState is an asynchronous function, So it takes time to update the state

```
const [filterParam, setFilterParam] = useState<string>("?filter=");

  const onChosenFilterHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const content = e.target.value;
    const definePath = `${filterParam}${content}`
    if (e.target.checked) {
      dispatch(
        recipeAction.addFilters({
          content: content,
          filterName: props.filterName,
        })
      );
      // if you still need this don't know logic what you do with FilterParam
      setFilterParam(definePath); 
      navigate(definePath);
    }
```

Comment: I updated the post, my logic was to make an array of string and deal with this array by adding and removing items, but async state makes it hard. How can I solve it? is useMemo an option?

Comment: useMemo only memoizes the value I still do not get the point of what are you trying to say in the updated post. did you still not get the update state?

Comment: Well I want to have an array of strings, these strings is content from onChosenFilterHandler. Then I want loop through this array and define path like - for(const filterParam of filterParamArray) definedPath += filterParam. The problem is asynchronous state and I get the delayed URL, with only "?filter" for example.